# Dynamically create tables based on the values from another table

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a BigQuery table that looks like this:

| country_code | value |
| --- | --- |
| DE | 100 |
| UK | 100 |
| US | 100 |
| DE | 100 |

The table gets updated periodically and the countries can de be different (new ones are added and others removed). I need to build an Airflow task for Cloud Composer that will:

- create a new table for each new country added and insert the data from the value column in it
- if the table already exists only append the new data from the value column to it
- do nothing for countries that are removed

For the above example the output will be 3 new tables for DE (2 rows), US and UK (one row each).

How can I dynamically create these tables in Airflow?

Answer (score 0):

The number of tasks here is dynamic as they will change based on the number of countries you have at a certain time. Therefore, you can benefit from [Airflow’s Dynamic tasks](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html). The steps to solve your issue would be as follows:

1. Using Airflow’s Operators (BigQueryOperator, Branching):

- Run a select query to the main table in BigQuery. You can use [BigQueryHook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.bigquery.BigQueryHook) and save the query’s output to an Airflow Variable.
- Create a Dynamic Task and execute a for loop within that reads the variable you saved in Step 1 and creates the required sub-tasks. The sub-tasks here would include a check:

  - If you have the table already, just execute an insert query from the main table to the country’s table.
  - If the table doesn’t exist, you can simply execute a "create table as" query or you can use the [BigQuery's operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/bigquery.html) to create the table using the specific schema you provide.
  - The  “if table exists” check step can done using [Airflow Branching](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.9/concepts.html#branching).

2. The same logic above, but using PythonOperator or [@task decorator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html) as the new approach. You would still use Dynamic tasks, but the sub-tasks would be a custom Python function where you would implement the logic you want. You can still benefit from BigQueryHook to interact with BigQuery.

Note: Unless you use a specific service account, you might need to grant the Cloud Composer's service account the required BQ permissions to run the above queries.